# Find the index of an element in an array created by toArray in JS/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a bunch of spans of class = "change" and each has a unique id. I created an array of those spans using:

```
var changesArray = $('.change').toArray()
```

I want to be able to get the index of the span in the array when I click on it. I tried:

```
$('.change').click(function(){
   var thisChange = $(this).attr('id');
   var thisChangeIndex = $.inArray(thisChange,changesArray);
});
```

But all I get is -1 for every .change I click on.

I'm a bit of a newbie with this type of code. Help?

Comment: toArray return array of DOM nodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `toArray` method says

> Retrieve all the elements contained in the jQuery set, as an array.

You are looking for a particular `id` in the array - that will never work.

If you want the index of the item you can use `.index()`

```js
 $('.change').click(function(){
   var thisChangeIndex = $('.change').index(this);
   console.log(thisChangeIndex);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span class="change">change1</span>
  <span class="change">change2</span>
  <span class="change">change3</span>
  <span class="change">change4</span>
 </div>
<div>
  <span class="change">change5</span>
  <span class="change">change6</span>
  <span class="change">change7</span>
  <span class="change">change8</span>
 </div>
```

Comment: So I don't really need an array at all. Huh. Well, that makes things a bit simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep a plain array of the unique ID's only:

```
var changesArrayIds = $('.change').toArray().map(function(x) { return x.id; });
```

Then this line should work fine:

```
var thisChangeIndex = $.inArray(thisChange, changesArrayIds);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using `.toArray` that works http://codepen.io/8odoros/pen/JKWxqz

```
var changesArray = $('.change').toArray();
$('.change').click(function(){
    var thisChange = $(this).attr('id');
    var thisChangeIndex = -1;
    $.each( changesArray, function( i, val ) {
      if( thisChange==val.id)  thisChangeIndex= i;
    }); 
    console.log(thisChangeIndex);
});
```

Comment: Can you explain what is going on in the $.each function?

Comment: [Check this](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/), it iterates over the array's objects. Gets two parameters (here `i` and `val`) that keep the current index and the current object.

Answer (score -1):

When you call `toArray`, you get an array of all the DOM nodes, not the jquery objects. You can search on `this` instead of `$(this)`:

```
var changesArray = $('.change').click(function(){
   var thisChangeIndex = $.inArray(this,changesArray);
}).toArray();
```

Comment: A downvote without a comment. How humorous. Since the code itself works, it would be nice if the voter would care to comment? This version does no extra search of the `.change` elements and in such a way is closer to the original question. (Of course the same could be done without toArray and buffering the jQuery object, but that's besides the point)

Comment: I'm not sure that this what I need because, if I'm reading this correctly, it only creates the array with the click event, right? I need the array in place for some other functions as well independent of this particular click event.

Comment: @Josh no, you're mistaken - the `toArray` is simply chained after the creation of a `click` event - so the array persists for use later as well as being used within the event handler